# Render a different template in backbone.js in same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a View that is already rendering a collection of posts:

```
Social.Views.StreamsIndex = Backbone.View.extend({

  template: JST['streams/index'],

  render: function(){
    $(this.el).html(this.template({
        entries: this.collection.toJSON()
    }));
    return this;
  }
});
```

Now I have to comment on a post for which I have to render a different template for comment:

```
Social.Views.StreamsIndex = Backbone.View.extend({

  template: JST['streams/index'],
  events: {
    'submit .comment_submit': 'comment_create'
  },
  comment_create: function(event) {
    //create comment code
```

After creating I want to do something like this, so that it can render comment template

```
    $("#comment).html(this.template1({
        comment: comment
    }));
  }
});
```

Is it possible to render a two templates from the same view?

Edited: (Adding View)

```
Social.Views.StreamsIndex = Backbone.View.extend({

template: JST['streams/index'],
template1: JST['streams/comment'],

events: {
    'submit .comment_submit': 'comment_create'
},

initialize: function(){
    this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
    this.model = new Social.Models.StreamsIndex();
    this.model.bind('comment_createSuccess', this.comment_createSuccess);
},

render: function(){
    $(this.el).html(this.template({
        entries: this.collection.toJSON()
    }));
    return this;
},

comment_create: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    post_id = $(event.currentTarget).attr("data-post-id");
    href = $(event.currentTarget).attr('action');
    comment_text = $("#comment_txt_"+post_id).val();
    this.model.create_comment(href, post_id, comment_text); // this sends ajax request and post the comment to server
},

comment_createSuccess: function(data, post_id) {
    this.$("#comment_for_post_"+post_id).append(this.template1({
      comment: data
    }));
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's absolutely no problem here as templates are anyway not a part of Backbone's structure. I only have one remark, which is that you should use `this.$` inside your view (it's a shortcut for `this.$el.find`, so you'll only find descendants of your view's el).

So...

```
this.$('#comment').append(this.template1({ // changed to append to be used several times
    comment: comment
}));
```

**Edit:**
About your context problem:

```
this.model.bind('comment_createSuccess', this.comment_createSuccess);
```

Here you can use the 3rd argument of `bind` to set the context of the callback:

```
this.model.bind('comment_createSuccess', this.comment_createSuccess, this);
```

`this` in your callback (`comment_createSuccess`) will now be your view.
I personally would rather use [Events#listenTo](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) that would automatically bind the context:

```
this.listenTo(this.model, 'comment_createSuccess', this.comment_createSuccess);
```

Comment: Cool. When i try i'm getting this error: "this.$ is not a function". Am i missing anything?

Comment: @Srikanth post your whole view, you may have a context problem ([source](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar)).

Comment: I have Edited my question with View

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks a lot for this help. I did this "this.listenTo(this.model, 'comment_createSuccess', this.comment_createSuccess)" and it works like a charm.